# Couldn't Discover Peripheral in Core Bluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I've iPhone app and I want to connect with bluetooth device to get Glucose Measurements. You can find the device from [here](http://www.taidoc.com/Blood-Glucose-Monitoring-System-TD-4257.html).

After reading Apple documentation about Core Bluetooth I started reading these [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/52080/introduction-core-bluetooth-building-heart-rate-monitor). Also I get the services ID's for bluetooth devices from these link [here](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServicesHome.aspx)

So I started to code like in the tutorial after understanding the basics.

And these my Code:

```
#define POLARH7_HRM_DEVICE_INFO_SERVICE_UUID @"180A" // for Device Information service.
#define POLARH7_HRM_HEART_RATE_SERVICE_UUID @"1808" // For Glucose service.

NSArray *services = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:POLARH7_HRM_HEART_RATE_SERVICE_UUID], [CBUUID UUIDWithString:POLARH7_HRM_DEVICE_INFO_SERVICE_UUID]];
CBCentralManager *centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
[centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:services options:nil];
self.centralManager = centralManager;
```

And I've implemented the delegates for CBCentralManagerDelegate and CBPeripheralDelegate

I receive a notification for `centralManagerDidUpdateState`

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    // Determine the state of the peripheral
    if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered off");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unauthorized");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnknown) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unknown");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is unsupported on this platform");
    }
}
```

My NSLog logs : `CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready.`

But I did not receive a notification for `central didDiscoverPeripheral`.

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSString *localName = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey];
    if ([localName length] > 0) {
        NSLog(@"Found the heart rate monitor: %@", localName);
        [self.centralManager stopScan];
        self.polarH7HRMPeripheral = peripheral;
        peripheral.delegate = self;
        [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
    }
}
```

These method is not being called.

So the central (my iPhone) couldn't discover the Peripheral which is my Glucose device.

I couldn't find the device when I search for it from Setting ->Bluetooth.

Comment: Try: `[centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];`, then we'll see. I didn't see if your device was really BLE or not with your link, and did `centralManagerDidUpdateState` when to `CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn` and then you did the scan?

Comment: Tried to make these [centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
but still didn't get notification in didDiscoverPeripheral delegate.

Answer (score 0):

If `centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:` is never called, this likely means that there is no peripheral with one of provided CBUUIDs. You could try to provide `nil` instead of the services-array and check if there is any peripheral available (don't do this in production mode).

Comment: Tried to make these [centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil]; but still didn't get notification in didDiscoverPeripheral delegate.

Comment: But the problem yesterday I've connected to the device and I recived a notification in centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI
and I can log the name of the device, these means that the device is Low energy device !!!
But now I couldn't connect to it !!
Even I tried to put the code on different place on the project it didn't give any response !!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I figured out the problem after sending email to TaiDoc company they told me that these device dose not support iPhone bluetooth integration.

I tried to connect with [Tom-Tom GPS watch](http://sports.tomtom.com/en_us/)  and it's connected successfully :)
So I think the problem of the issue is a Hardware issue.